# Don't RF devices need to be shielded to pass FCC?

Tags: rf, shielding, fcc

I'm looking at [this device](https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=Y&application_id=ArHLoiiciR2K3widvDmsAA%3D%3D&fcc_id=2AC2FHONEY). [Internally](https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/GetApplicationAttachment.html?id=2374618), the Bluetooth chip isn't shielded but it still seems to have passed FCC. Addition to that, there was no Modular Approval Request Letter, which typically requires one to declare that the radio elements are shielded.

So, how come this could still be approved even without an Approval Request Letter or shield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think board level shielding is a requirement to pass FCC, unless it's modular, and even then I'm not entirely sure.

Also, that's the same reason there's not a Modular Approval Request Letter because it's not modular. It looks like a self-contained product, not something that connects to something else. I think you're treating it as a Bluetooth module, which do have shielding and are meant to be used with something else, but what you linked isn't a module.

Comment: Do you know why modules need be shielded? Or at least, to declare that a shield is in place?

Comment: I think it's simply because you don't know what the end-user is going to combine it with. "The shielding of the RF section is to help prevent RF coupling when installed in a host. It is therefore not sufficient for the module to meet only the stand alone configuration requirement. Other circuitry such as flash memory, a temperature sensor, input voltage regulators, input data buffering circuits, etc. may not be RF, and therefore need not be shielded. However, the grantee must use good engineering judgment to reduce any possible RF coupling that might affect a host."